# Lightning Url hack from custom button

Tags: lightning, custom-button, urlhacking

I have created custom button which is showing on detailed page and content behaviour is URL. My requirement is on account page there is two field there first one is name and another field is phone. When i click to custom clone button i need name should be available and phone number should be blank if this phone value is on record their.

```
/lightning/o/Account/new?&recordTypeId=01228000000SxLXAA0
     &defaultFieldValues=name={!URLENCODE(Account.Name)},{!Account.Phone}=''
```

this thing is not working when i click it's opening blank form in lightning.

Comment: see this [tutorial](https://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-url-hacking-for-lightning-tutorial/) - you want `phone=''`, not `{!Account.Phone}=''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below:

```
/lightning/o/Account/new?recordTypeId=01228000000SxLXAA0&defaultFieldValues=Name={!URLENCODE(Account.Name)},Phone=
```

[image]

[Pre-populate field values](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_general_lex_navigate_to_record_dfv.htm)

Thanks,